# Why was my "Not an Answer" flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Yesterday I flagged [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13600/is-sanguine-bond-exquisite-blood-a-potential-game-ender/29078#29078) as "Not an Answer". The full text is

> Curious then what if you have Grand Abolisher on the battlefield and initiate the effects of Sanguine Bond and Exquisite Blood. Grand Abolisher effectively shuts down your opponents ability to respond.

This is clearly a followup question; it expresses curiosity about adding an additional constraint to the scenario in question, and it makes not attempt to answer the question. So, why was my flag declined?

Comment: Looks like a text book "not an answer" to me. I'll let Pat reply, but I'm guessing he was short on time and just made a mistake.

Comment: I have also flagged this post as "Not an Answer" and it was also declined.

Comment: I suppose this: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/1372/14416
answers the question.

Comment: @tsuma534 I hope not. Unlike the answers discussed in that question, the "Not an Answer" flag does actually apply here.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I won't agree with the "unlike" part. Q: How do I use deck randomizers? A: Don't use deck randomizers. Kinda looks like "doesn't attempt to answer" to me.

Comment: The point there was not to reopen that argument. All of the existing answers there explain why NAA does not apply in that case.

Comment: @ire_and_curses Note that Pat in that answer said that he routinely does not actually look at the question, so he may be more prone to making this kind of mistake whether or not he's short on time.